# Limit without doing arithmetic with infinity

Tags: limits

How do you show this without doing arithmetic with infinity?
$$\lim \limits_{z \to {-\infty}} \frac{1}{1 + e^{-z}} = 0$$

Comment: What do you mean by "doing arithmetic with infinity"? Does this refer to the fact that $\lim_{x\to-\infty} (1+e^{-x}) = \infty$?

Comment: @DavidK See my answer

Comment: Do you mean, using the epsilon-delta definition of a limit? That doesn't use any infinity.

Comment: @RobertGreen I misread the $z$s as $x$s in the original question. I have a new pair of glasses on order; I hope they arrive soon. Either on the real line or on the complex plane, however, my question is whether OP somehow thinks that an answer like yours is in any way "doing arithmetic with infinity". On the contrary, it does not (and I believe it is correct).

Comment: Example: $$\lim \limits_{x \to \infty} \frac{2x}{x + 1}=2$$ 
using the law: the limit of a quotient is the quotient of the limit, it becomes:

$${\lim \limits_{x \to \infty}2x}\over{{\lim \limits_{x \to \infty} x} + {\lim \limits_{x \to \infty} 1}}$$
which becomes "arithmetic with $\infty$":
$${\infty}\over{\infty + 1}$$
alternatively, one can do this: 
$$\lim \limits_{x \to \infty} \frac{2x}{1 + x}\cdot\frac{1\over x}{1\over x}$$

$${\lim \limits_{x \to \infty}2}\over{{\lim \limits_{x \to \infty} {1\over x}} + {\lim \limits_{x \to \infty} {1}}}$$
Giving:
$${2\over{0 + 1}}=2$$

Answer (score 0):

I guess that by $z\to-\infty$ you mean $x = \mathfrak{Re}(z)\to -\infty$ and $y = \mathfrak{Im}(z)\to 0$. Now $$1+e^{-z)} = 1 + e^{-x}e^{iy} = 1 + e^{-x} \cos(y) - i e^{-x} \sin(y)$$ so that $$|1+e^{-z)}|^2 \geq (1+e^{-x} \cos(y) )^2 \to +\infty$$ as $z\to-\infty$ (with the interpretation of "$z\to-\infty$" given above) which implies $|1+e^{-z}| \to +\infty$ as $z\to -\infty$, which finally implies that $$\left| \frac{1}{1+e^{-z}} \right| = \frac{1}{|1+e^{-z}|} \to 0$$ as $z\to -\infty$, which means but $\lim \limits_{z \to {-\infty}} \frac{1}{1 + e^{-z}} = 0$.